# How to run Windows Photo Viewer in Safe Mode?

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode, windows-photo-viewer

How can I get Windows Photo Viewer to run in Safe Mode? I'm running Microsoft Windows 7.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can't you just navigate to the photo viewer application file and run it?

Comment: Ahh okay. Sorry I didn't know that. Can you use any other photo viewer? Or do you *have* to use the windows one?

Answer (score 2):

## Quick analysis

During its startup phase, Windows Photo Viewer uses the `GetSystemMetrics` [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) function to check whether the system was started in [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-safe-mode#1TC=windows-7). If that's the case, it will display the following message:

> Windows Photo Viewer does not work in safe mode.  If you want to view pictures or videos, restart your computer normally.

The actual code is located inside the `PhotoViewer.dll` library file, which can be usually found in these folders:

- **Windows Vista**

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Gallery
  ```
- **Windows 7 and later**

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer
  ```

### Further reading

- [Windows Photo Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Viewer)
- [GetSystemMetrics function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

## Workaround

Use Paint or a third-party image viewer such as [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/), [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnview/), or [FastStone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm).

---

## Patching the limitation

The library file can be patched in order to fool the viewer into thinking the operating system wasn't started in safe mode. Despite what the warning message says, all features except printing appear to be working fine.

**Note** While the patch *might* have some side effects, it doesn't seem the case according to my tests.

1. Open the program folder, which is usually located here:

   ```
    C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer
   ```
2. Copy the `PhotoViewer.dll` file to the desktop, and rename it to `PhotoViewer2.dll`.
3. Open `PhotoViewer2.dll` file using a [hex editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) (e.g. [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)).
4. Go to the proper hexadecimal offset. See below.
5. Change the first two bytes there to `3BC0`, and save the changes.
6. Copy the saved file to the program folder.
7. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7), type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   cd /d "%programfiles%\Windows Photo Viewer"
   ```
8. Replace the original library with the patched one by running these commands:

   ```
   taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
   takeown /f PhotoViewer.dll /a
   icacls PhotoViewer.dll /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544:F
   ren PhotoViewer.dll PhotoViewer.dll.old
   ren PhotoViewer2.dll PhotoViewer.dll
   start explorer
   ```

### Offsets

- **Windows Vista SP2 x86 (32-bit)**

  ```
  0x19741
  ```
- **Windows Vista SP2 x64 (64-bit)**

  ```
  0x252F8
  ```
- **Windows 7 SP1 x86 (32-bit)**

  ```
  0x9DFF
  ```
- **Windows 7 SP1 x64 (64-bit)**

  ```
  0x689E6
  ```
- **Windows 8 x86 (32-bit)**

  ```
  0x711DE
  ```
- **Windows 8 x64 (64-bit)**

  ```
  0x8E785
  ```
- **Windows 8.1 x86 (32-bit)**

  ```
  0x70CF9
  ```
- **Windows 8.1 x64 (64-bit)**

  ```
   0x8E3F9
  ```

### Screenshots

#### Before

[image: Screenshot 1]

#### After

[image: Screenshot 2]

*Click for larger view.*

Comment: Hi thanks for your help here but i can't find my relevant Offset.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need windows photo viewer to view pictures at all. All you have to do is right click on the picture, then navigate to the option: "Open With." Then click on Paint. A 100% zoomed image of that file will be shown.